# Why is adverb "why" used in this sentence "It's why I love you"?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-adverbs

I've read on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz2l2vit-_U) "It's why I love you" What was the reason adverb "why" was used after "it's"?

Comment: Because why means the reason.

Answer (score 1):

> *It's* [*why I love you*].

"Why" is a question word in the bracketed subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), which is functioning as an obligatory complement of "be" ("is").

The meaning is

"It's the answer to the question 'Why do I love you?'"